# jquery function only triggers once

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery function to delete a file from a list and then reload the list via AJAX.

It works perfectly...but only once.

```
        $(".delbutton").click(function(){
        var filename = $(this).attr("id");
        var info = 'pid=<?php echo $_GET["pid"]; ?>&f=' + filename;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "deleteupload.php",
                data: info,
                success: function(){
                    $('#filelist').load("files.php?pid=<?php echo $_GET["pid"]; ?>");
                }
            });
    });

});
```

The HTML is

```
<div id="filelist"> 
     <img src='/images/cross.png' alt='delete' class='delbutton' id='OUCH.gif'>&nbsp;OUCH.gif<br>

<img src='/images/cross.png' alt='delete' class='delbutton' id='xmas_tree.png'>&nbsp;xmas_tree.png<br>
    </div>
```

Another jquery function on the page continues to work when this one doesn't so it isn't jquery that is broken.

Someone is going to see the problem, I can't.

Comment: @Steve - Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: peculiar way to assign an id :)

Comment: You're injecting values into PHP-generated jQuery code?!

Comment: If you think you know better, why don't you add something useful instead of snide criticism.

Comment: @Christopher, nope, no errors in console.

Comment: It's just very, umm, unusual.  It also prevents isolation of your JS files from your HTML.  Instead I would drop `pid` into a hidden input element, and then have the JS read that.

Comment: Thank you.  A useful answer helps me learn (which I have done) - HTML and JS now quarantined :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble is that you are binding to elements that match `.delbutton`, but you then replace them with the `$('#filelist').load` call.  The standard binding functions such as `click` bind to the *element*, not to the *selector*.

The easy way around this is to use either [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). I prefer the `delegate` syntax:

```
$('#filelist').delegate(".delbutton", 'click', function(){
     // your code here
});
```

NB There are probably better places to put a filename than in the `id` attribute...  I'd suggest using a `data-url` attribute instead. (See [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).)

Comment: Thanks for that, having rtfm, it looks like the solution and I have learned something...except...if the only code I put in there is alert('testing'); it doesn't trigger.  According to the manual your (and therefore my) syntax looks right.  Am I missing something?

Comment: HAH!  delegate was introduced in 1.4.2 I was using 1.3.x :P  Now it works.  Thanks

Comment: I also had this issue, delegate fixed it.